# AngularJS 1.4: Select List Value not Initializing Correctly when List is Inserted with $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-compile

Here's some quick background info. I just upgraded to Angular 1.4. I'm using an API written in C# for my server-side calls.

A section of my page shows 2 select lists (Project & Sub-project). Both are supposed to default to "(Select a ______)", which I list as the first option of each select with "value" of 0. The appropriate ng-model variables are initialized to 0.

The actual HTML code for the select lists is being generated on the server side using string concatenation, passed to the client via $http, and inserted using a directive that calls $compile (not ideal at all, but my client has pretty much chained me to this API). Prior to the 1.4 update, everything was working nicely.

Now, my Project select list is defaulting to nothing. When I inspect the element, this is what I see...

```
<select ng-change="updateSubProjList()" ng-model="curProjID">
    <option value="? number:0 ?"></option>
    <option value="0">(Select a Project)</option>
    <option value="1">First Project</option>
    <option value="2">Second Project</option>
    ...
</select>
```

...with that first "? number:0 ?" entry being the one that is currently selected. My Sub-project select list still initializes just fine, which makes this even more odd.

I know that there were some updates to $compile in the update to AngularJS 1.4, but I can't figure out a solution to my problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `curProjID`?

Comment: It's initialized to 0 when the controller loads.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There seems to be a change in 1.4 related to how the selected option is matched against `ngModel` by comparing the `value` attribute in `<option value="0">` - it now requires to explicitly use a string to match, rather than allowing for an integer.

In fact, the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/directive/select) clearly states:

> The value of a `select` directive used without `ngOptions` is always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string value, you must either explicitly convert it using a directive ... or use `ngOptions` to specify the set of options.

To fix, change the initialized value of `$scope.curProjID` to be a string:

```
$scope.curProjID = "0"; // instead of $scope.curProjID = 0;
```

When there is no match (and there isn't, unless you assign a string `"0"`), `select` adds an "unknown" option: `<option value="? number:0 ?"></option>`.

Comment: This is absolutely right. Thank you! For anyone wondering, my 2nd select statement worked because the options came from and array of objects loaded using "ng-options", as opposed to a giant concatenated string.

Comment: As a quick fix I just changed my ng-model binding to include the "toString()"<select ng-model="reason.toString()">

Comment: @JeremyChild, that is rather a "quick break"... it might work for matching, but it would not update the model (`$scope.reason`) when the selection changes, which is the whole purpose of `ng-model`

Comment: Well done, Angular! My face after reading this answer was like :O.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way: using a directive implementing a parser and a formatter. See http://plnkr.co/edit/JZPay8jgm5AXKGXDCjSb

thankx goes to narretz!

Pseudo code:

```
<select convert-number ng-model="x">
   <option value="100">100</option>
   <option value="200">200</option>
</select>


app.directive('convertNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return parseInt(value, 10);
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value.toString();
      });      
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  This is a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Instead of making sure that my JavaScript code uses string all over the place, I did the following:

> Removed the `<option ...>` items from the HTML file
>
> Introduced a list into JavaScript, similar to:

```
var orderQuantities = [
        { id: 100, text: '100' },
        { id: 200, text: '200' },
        { id: 300, text: '300' },
];
```

> Did make sure that orderQuantities is visible in the scope
>
> Used `ng-option` in the `select` tag as follow:

```
<select ng-model="vm.entity.OrderQuantity" ng-options="orderQuantity.id as orderQuantity.text for orderQuantity in vm.orderQuantities"></select>
```

Comment: With this approach, what get bound inside `vm.entity.OrderQuantity` ? Was it only the id (that is, 100, 200, 300) or was it entire selected object (e.g.  `{ id: 200, text: '200' }`) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="x">
   <option value="100">100</option>
   <option value="200">200</option>
</select>

scope.x = '200'
```

or read this doc.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration